# Is it possible to to define a relationship between two tables that are related through another table in Yii2?

Tags: model, yii2, relationship

I have three tables related to each other. The tables are `reservations`, `vehicle_schedules` and `vehicles`.

Table `reservations (reservations_id, schedule_id, other_fields)`
Table `schedules (schedule_id, vehicle_id, other_fields)`
Table `vehicles (vehicle_id, reg_number, model ...)`

Now, having the three tables, I want to display the values of the `vehicles` table from the `reservations` table `GridView`, i.e be able to perform `sort`, `search` etc of the `vehicle.reg_number`. Displaying the values of the table is not the problem but now trying to manipulate the `ReservationsSearch` model to be able to get this values during search and sorting proves to be a problem since table `reservations` has no direct relation to table `vehicles` but only relates to it via the `vehicle_schedules` table.

Anyone with an idea how to go about this?

Reservations view.php

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'reservation_id:integer:Ticket #',
            'schedule.vehicle.reg_number',
            [
            'attribute' => 'Customer Name',
            'value' => 'customer.name'
            ],
            [
            'attribute' => 'Officer Name',
            'value' => 'officer.first_name'
            ],
            'schedule.route.displayName:text:Route',
            'amount_paid',
            // 'datetime',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Reservations Model

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use app\models\CDbExpression;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "reservations".
 *
 * @property integer $reservation_id
 * @property integer $schedule_id
 * @property integer $customer_id
 * @property integer $officer_id
 * @property integer $seat_number
 * @property string $amount_paid
 * @property string $datetime
 *
 * @property Customers $customer
 * @property User $officer
 * @property VehicleSchedules $schedule
 */
class Reservations extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $mobile_number;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'reservations';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['schedule_id', 'customer_id', 'officer_id', 'seat_number'], 'required'],
            [['schedule_id', 'customer_id', 'officer_id', 'seat_number'], 'integer'],
            [['amount_paid'], 'number'],
            [['datetime', 'mobile_number'], 'safe'],
            [['customer_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Customers::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['customer_id' => 'customer_id']],
            [['officer_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['officer_id' => 'id']],
            [['schedule_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => VehicleSchedules::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['schedule_id' => 'schedule_id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'reservation_id' => 'Ticket Number',
            'schedule_id' => 'Schedule ID',
            'customer_id' => 'Customer Name',
            'officer_id' => 'Officer',
            'seat_number' => 'Seat Number',
            'amount_paid' => 'Amount Paid',
            'datetime' => 'Date & Time',
            'mobile_number' => 'Mobile Number',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Customers::className(), ['customer_id' => 'customer_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getOfficer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Staff::className(), ['id' => 'officer_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSchedule()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(VehicleSchedules::className(), ['schedule_id' => 'schedule_id']);
    }
```

ReservationsSearch Model

```
    <?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Reservations;

/**
 * ReservationsSearch represents the model behind the search form about `app\models\Reservations`.
 */
class ReservationsSearch extends Reservations
{
    public $customer;
    public $vehicle;
    public $officer;
    public $route;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['reservation_id', 'schedule_id', 'customer_id', 'officer_id', 'seat_number'], 'integer'],
            [['amount_paid'], 'number'],
            [['datetime', 'customer', 'vehicle', 'officer', 'route'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Reservations::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        // $query->joinWith(['customers', 'vehicles', 'staff', 'stations']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'reservation_id' => $this->reservation_id,
            'schedule_id' => $this->schedule_id,
            'customer_id' => $this->customer_id,
            'officer_id' => $this->officer_id,
            'seat_number' => $this->seat_number,
            'amount_paid' => $this->amount_paid,
            'datetime' => $this->datetime,
        ]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: May be helpful to you . Take a look here : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#working-with-model-relations

Comment: Hi @vijay, I think that one works for two tables that are directly related. In my case, the tables are related via another table. Proves somehow tricky but I know there is a way.

Comment: [Relations via a Junction Table](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#junction-table)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: as Bizley also mentioned. You are searching for the usage of a "junction table" this will help you http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/851/yii2-gridview-sorting-and-searching-with-a-junction-table-column-many-to-many-relationship/

Comment: Thank you Bizley and BHoft, your answers have come in handy. I am confident that I can proceed from this point.